# Как сделать чтоб при нажатии кнопки в Swift 2, открылось диалоговое окно

Tags: xcode, swift, button, события

Как сделать чтоб при нажатии кнопки в Swift 2  открылось диалоговое окно? Использую XCode 7 не судите строго я новичок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Именно диалоговое окно создается с помощью UIAlertController:

1. Создается UIALertController
2. Создаются кнопки и действия, совершаемые при нажатии на них
3. Добавляются кнопки в контроллер
4. Вызывается показ вьюшки контроллера

   ```
   let ac = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
   let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (_) in
       print("OK!")
   }
   let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (_) in
       print("Cancel!")
   }
   ac.addAction(okAction)
   ac.addAction(cancelAction)
   self.present(ac, animated: true)
   ```

Comment: К тому же, в показываемый контроллер можно добавить поля для ввода текста

Answer (score 0):

Если через `Storyboard` то это делается очень просто:

1) Зажимаете кнопку на первом `ViewController` и тянете на второй `ViewController` в появившемся окне выбираете `Present Modally`.

[image: Кнопка]

Comment: а можно это как-то кодом расписать ?

Comment: к примеру так button.msg="Hello"